# external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace); } error fix

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new to flutter and i am trying to complete an  assignment which involves creating a log in and sign up screen and then integrating them with firebase authentication. i have done the integration with the firebase auth in my sign up screen but when i try to test it in the app i get taken to the erros_patch.dart file in my project and the error message on line 27 whic is : external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
}

is highlighted and afterwards the app in my androi device won't respond . please help me out.

i'm new to flutter and as such i'm lost on what to do

Comment: `Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);` is not interesting. That's a function that throws an exception. You need to inspect the stack trace to determine what's calling that function and why.  Nobody can help you further without those details.